# How to reuse the httpservlet request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

Hi is there anyway to make a request persistent? In my web application I need to check what Check-box has the user ticked, i get this value by using Request.getPart("Convert File"); After this I need to upload the file the user selects but when I parse the request I get a null value because the request has already been used. Is there any way around this issue? Like saving the request? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called session

Comment: Can you explain some more? See both checking what check-box the user ticked and uploading the file to the tomcat server are done on the same Servlet. Through the post method I check which check-box has been ticked, once I get this I then call the upload method passing the request. It is then in this upload method that the request is null. Do you think sessions would solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the information in the request for future use, you have to store the information in a wider scope, for example in the session.

```
//Storing value
Session session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("key", "value");

//Retrieve value
session.getAttribute("key")
```

Comment: Can you explain some more? See both checking what check-box the user ticked and uploading the file to the tomcat server are done on the same Servlet. Through the post method I check which check-box has been ticked, once I get this I then call the upload method passing the request. It is then in this upload method that the request is null. Do you think sessions would solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use httpSession. You can use api like:

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("Key", "Value");
```

And later on when user revisits, you could check same attribute like:

```
session.getAttribute("Key");
```

Comment: Can you explain some more? See both checking what check-box the user ticked and uploading the file to the tomcat server are done on the same Servlet. Through the post method I check which check-box has been ticked, once I get this I then call the upload method passing the request. It is then in this upload method that the request is null. Do you think sessions would solve this issue?